# Como saber a conexão atual que o sistema está usando no CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: cakephp, postgresql, banco-de-dados

Olá, estou trabalhando com dois tipos de conexões em bancos de dados com configurações diferentes. Quero saber como eu posso pegar a atual conexão que a página está executando de forma dinâmica.

Atualmente eu uso isso:

```
 use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

 $conexao = ConnectionManager::get('default');
 $conexao->execute('set local "funcap.usuario" = "build";');
```

Mas isso me retorne informações sobre a conexão fixa `'default'`, eu queria algo mais dinâmico como:

```
 $conexão = ConnectioXxx::getCurrent();
```

Estou usando o CakePHP na versão 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa resposta foi tirada do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213709/get-current-database-name-cakephp-3)
.

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$this->{$modelName}->connection()->config();
```